# Is there a term or a phrase for something that is both literally and figuratively true?

Tags: synonyms

For example, when I tried to do my best at dancing, I "put my best foot forward".  This is literally true because in dancing I put one foot in front of the other, but it's also figuratively true because I was sincerely giving it my best effort.  Is there a word or a phrase that describes something that is both literally and figuratively true?

Comment: True in all senses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add "in both senses of the [word or phrase]." For instance, "I put my best foot forward" becomes either "In both senses of the phrase, I put my best foot forward" or "I put my best foot forward, in both senses of the phrase."

Answer (score 1):

"Pun [not] intended", perhaps.